# How to delete all schemas in postgres

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I'm using `django-tenants`, and for some tests I need to delete all schemas at once, so I was wondering how could I delete all schemas with a single sentence/script from **postgresql shell**, because deleting one by one is not scalable.

Thx so much.

Comment: Would it be worth it to drop the entire database and create it again?

Comment: You might wanna check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627223/how-to-drop-all-schemas-in-postgresql-with-sql-query) for a script that drops all schemas. Then put that script in a file `myscript.sql` and run it using `psql -d mydatabase -U myuser -p 5432 -h myhostname -f myscript.sql`.

Comment: Yes, drop the database.

Comment: I've se seen that its not as easy as dropping the database, because there are still connections alive, so postgres won't let me do it. About [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627223/how-to-drop-all-schemas-in-postgresql-with-sql-query) proposed in the link, that does what I want, I don't understand it. Could someone explain a bit please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting all schemas you must use dynamic SQL. And schema names you can get from statistic system tables (example: information_schema). Example Query:

```
do
$body$
declare
    f_rec record;
begin
    
    for f_rec in 
        SELECT schema_name::text
        FROM information_schema.schemata
        where schema_name <> 'public'
    loop 
        execute 'DROP SCHEMA ' || f_rec.schema_name || ' CASCADE';
    end loop;   
    
end;
$body$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Comment: Finally I used your code avoiding to delete some of system's important schemas: `do
$body$
declare
    f_rec record;
begin
    
    for f_rec in 
        SELECT schema_name::text
        FROM information_schema.schemata
        where schema_name <> 'pg_toast' and
        schema_name <> 'pg_catalog' and
        schema_name <> 'public' and
        schema_name <> 'information_schema'
    loop 
        execute 'DROP SCHEMA ' || f_rec.schema_name || ' CASCADE';
    end loop;   
    
end;
$body$
language 'plpgsql';`